# Cant setup postgreSQL to for stored procedures in Tcl

Tags: postgresql

I've gotten some stored procedures to work with `LANGUAGE plpgsql`, but now I want to start writing stored procedures using `LANGUAGE pltcl` but I'm having problems setting things up.

I've installed some extra packages (although I'm not sure why the website I was looking at wanted me to also install the package for Perl, but I did it anyway).

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-pltcl-15
sudo apt-get install postgresql-plperl-15
sudo apt install postgresql-15-postgis-3-scripts
```

I've seen in pgAdmin there is something about Languages and the only one there is plpgsql. I don't know what to do about that, I don't know what options to select if I try to add pltcl here, and I haven't seen any websites saying to change this. So I've left this alone.

I've been reading about `CREATE EXTENSION pltcl;` command and it just doesn't seem to work.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pltcl;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/pltcl.control": No such file or directory
```

I can't find any help about this error message. Any ideas?

Comment: You installed the software for PostgreSQL v15, so you shouldn't be surprised if it isn't available in PostgreSQL v14.

Comment: Well postgresql-pltcl-14 wasn't available so when I had to install postgresql-pltcl-15 so when I run the command CREATE EXTENSION pltcl; how do I get it to point at the right version of the server?

Comment: You are saying "I couldn't find a key, so I took a fork, now why can't I open the door?". If all fails, you can build from source.

Comment: **To your question add**: 1) OS and version.  2) The repo you are using for the packages. 3) How you installed the Postgres 14 server?

Comment: (1) Ubuntu 23.04 (2) I dont know, I'm not using any extra repo's I haven't added any repo's for this installation. I'm just using the main repo for Ubuntu 23.04. (3) I cant remember it was about a month or two ago, I just installed the latest version which would have been version 15, so I have no idea why it's also referring to version 14, it just makes no sense at all.  Everything should be pointing to version 15, I have version 15 of PostgreSQL but APT INSTALL is installing the pltcl extension into the folder for 15 and then CREATE EXTENSION can't find the file in the folder for version 14.